# How to send query from nodejs server to open data server?

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, api

I'm working with open data: https://data.sfgov.org/Economy-and-Community/Mobile-Food-Facility-Permit/rqzj-sfat

The open data site allows to query the data, and example query is below: https://soda.demo.socrata.com/resource/4tka-6guv.json?$where=magnitude > 3.0
However, this, I imagine is URL querying. If I had to get the same object on my nodejs server, how would I format the query to receive the json objects on the node server?

Are there any security threats or exposing threats to querying for data this way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the easiest way to do this is via [request](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request) package. You could do something like the following:

```
var request = require('request');

request('https://soda.demo.socrata.com/resource/4tka-6guv.json?$where=magnitude%3E3.0', function (err, res, body) {
  if (err) {
    //handle error
  } else {
    console.log(body); // and do stuff with your results
  }
});
```

If you run this, you'll see a print out of your result array. There aren't really any security threats with this. Your just doing a GET request from an open data source. Pretty standard stuff. Same kind of transactions happen everyday all over the web.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [request](http://blog.modulus.io/node.js-tutorial-how-to-use-request-module) module. Super useful

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [soda-js library](https://github.com/socrata/soda-js).

Here is a MWE: just issue an `npm install soda-js` and then you can do something similar to:

```
const soda = require('soda-js');

const consumer = new soda.Consumer('datos.gov.co');

consumer.query()
  .withDataset('sus6-4i9j')
  .limit(5)
  .getRows()
    .on('success', function(rows) { console.log(rows); })
    .on('error', function(error) { console.error(error); });
```

In this example the endpoint being consumed is https://www.datos.gov.co/resource/sus6-4i9j.json, which returns a list of other APIs openly available in the [www.datos.gov.co](https://www.datos.gov.co) site ;).

The following is a portion of the output:

[image: Cool API output]

---

In your specific case, you can do

```
const soda = require('soda-js');

const consumer = new soda.Consumer('data.sfgov.org');

consumer.query()
  .withDataset('rqzj-sfat')
  .limit(5)
  .getRows()
    .on('success', function(rows) { console.log(rows); })
    .on('error', function(error) { console.error(error); });
```

Which will provide the data you need.